# .htaccess for a domain and subdomain robots to prevent crawling

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

domain.com - live server

dev.domain.com - dev server

Both with:

```
/public/robots.txt #which is for domain.com
/public/robots-dev.txt #which is for dev.domain.com
.htaccess
```

How to use the same .htaccess to select specific robots depending if it in **live** or **dev**?

I have tried this, but it is not working (part of the htaccess is to redirect non-https & www to https with non-www, please ignore that):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-%1\.txt [L] #this one
</IfModule>
```

Update: Below is the public/.htaccess

```
# GLOBAL RULES
# ============
# Directories Index protection
Options -Indexes

# Remove index.php from URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>

# Default Apache rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

# Robots.txt
RewriteRule  ^(robots\.txt)$ /robots [NC,L]

# Iframe calling
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
</IfModule>

# GTMetrix - Enable gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

    # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
# GTMetrix - Enable gzip compression

# GTMetrix Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
# GTMetrix Browser Caching
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ public/robots-dev.txt [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it does not work. Any way you can check? I have the same htaccess code as on top.

Comment: This suggested .htaccess code  should be kept in root .htaccess. Try `dev.domain.com/robots.txt` and tell what exact error do you get? Does `dev.domain.com/public/robots-dev.txt` work?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess is in root level, dev.domain.com/robots.txt still is fetching the domain.com/robots.txt (which is in public)

Comment: Just a correction from my previous comment, when I am going to dev.domain.com/robots.txt, it does not fetch robots-dev.txt, for the live it is working. I jsut need to prevent crawling on dev server to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I tried it, but it still does not work. I have updated the question with bold, maybe it will help.

Comment: Keep **only my suggested code** in your root .htaccess. Then answer all questions: Q1. Is `domain.com/robots.txt` loading `domain.com/public/robots.txt` ? Q2. Is `dev.domain.com/public/robots-dev.txt` loading correct file? Q3. Is there a separate `public/.htaccess`, if yes then provide that in question.

Comment: #Q1. Yes, #Q2. No (it is loading the public/robots.txt), #Q3. Yes there is another .htaccess in the public

Comment: I asked you to post `/public/.htaccess` if it exists but I don't see that in question. Please re-read `Q2`. I asked whether **`dev.domain.com/public/robots-dev.txt`** (not `dev.domain.com/robots.txt`) works from browser or not? Does `public/` folder have a valid file `robots-dev.txt`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I totally missed that one out. I have updated the question with the .htaccess in public. I can see there is a one line for robots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170281/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ponce).